# how can I create a 2d lists with two seperate functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to know how to write a two dimensional list with 3 rows and 3 columns. then write a nested loop that gets an integer from the user for each element in the list. then write 2 seperate functions to process the table:

main-creates the 2d list and fills it with values
add_rows-receives the list from the main and produces the sum/total of each row
add_col- recieves the list from the main and produces the sum/total of each colunm

Comment: If I've answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To create the 2-dimensional list you can create a list of lists. For your 3x3 list use something like

```
data = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
```

You already have the answer of how to fill the values, use nested loops:

```
for col in range(3):
     for row in range(3):
         data[col][row] = int(input("Enter {}x{}".format(row, col)))
```

Of course you'll need to add error checking to this code, but hopefully you get the idea.

Finally, to get the sum of each column you can use listbuilder notation like this:

```
result = [sum(col) for col in data]
```

To get the sum of rows you can use this algorithm

```
result = [0 for _ in range(ROWS)]

for row in range(ROWS):
    for col in range(COLS):
        result[row] += data[row][col]
```

Comment: this is what i got so far but the instructions also say that i should have 6 totals (1 for each row and 1 for each column) and this throwing me off
ROWS = 3
COLS = 3

def main():
    
    data = [[0,0,0],
            [0,0,0],
            [0,0,0]]

    for r in range (ROWS):
        for c in range (COLS):
            data [r][c] = int(input('Enter {}x{}'.format(ROWS,COLS)))

    result = [sum(COLS) for COLS in data]
    result2 = [sum(ROWS) for ROWS in data]

    print(result)
    print(result2)


main()

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate calculating the sum of rows.

Comment: should i then print out: print(result)?

Comment: Actually at the end of your add_rows and add_cols functions you should `return result`

Then in your main function, you save the returned result from add_rows/add_cols and print them there. Or you could print the result from within the function, but the function name implies that you want the result back. At this point, you're getting into things that depend on your design.